# modified android ACTION_VIEW intent

Tags: android, image, android-intent

I execute the following code:

> Uri uri =
>   Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
>   imageIdStr); Intent intent = new
>   Intent();
>   intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
>   intent.setData(uri);
>   activity.startActivity(intent);

which opens the image viewer activity but I don't want to see the navigation arrows as well as the items in the menu. I only want the zoom controls. Is it possible to have it like that ?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the application that's actually displaying the image. On Android 2.0 and older, it's probably the Gallery app. On many Android 2.1+ apps, it's probably CoolIris' gallery. If the user has one of the many gallery apps from the market installed, it's up to those apps. I highly doubt there's a standardized extra to control that.

If you're really concerned about what the image display looks like, then you should handle that yourself. If you're really just trying to display an image (and maybe add pinch-zoom support?), it's a reasonable scope.